# como ler Json no xe8

Tags: json, delphi-xe8

nao está funcionando no xe8 =/, sabe porque?

Json requestresponse1.context:

```
["1 - Album Linha Inglesa (f) 30x30 (a) 30x60 25 laminas (120 imagens)","1 - Cobertura Religioso, Ensaio e Recep\u00e7\u00e3o","2 - Fot\u00f3grafo(s)","1 - Making Of da noiva","1 - DVD com todas as fotos do album","1 - DVD com todas as fotos do evento","1 - Poster(s) 50x80","1 - Sessao de fotos apos o evento religioso","2 - SelfieCG"]
```

Comment: Adilerson, poderia adicionar o codigo que esta utilizando?

Comment: olha meu problema agora já é outro, rsrs! estou recebendo um Json de um restresponse o seguinte texto: 
{"erro":"0","usuario":"Rafael e Andressa","codigo":"249"}
se eu faço uma leitura pelo Json, retorna um erro. Mas se eu copio este texto para um bloco de notas e colo novamente no memo, o Json consegue ler normalmente, será que está vindo alguma formataçao especial??